# How should I fit radial basis function to 3D data in Scipy?

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation

I'm reasonably new here, so sorry if this is a basic question.

I have a dataset comprising several thousand 'hotspots'- small sections of 3D data, at most a few tens or hundreds datapoints each, and each arranged around a centre. I am (in Python) trying to fit each to a particular radial basis function, roughly of the form exp(-r)/r, and obtain the parameters of that fit for each hotspot. All the libraries I've seen that do this are ML-based and treat the hotspots as training data from which to obtain global parameters- but that's not what I need, because each hotspot should have different parameters and those variations contain meaningful information. scipy.optimize.RBF doesn't seem to allow you to retrieve the parameters it uses, unless I'm misreading the documentation. Is there any library that does this easily? Any advice would be very appreciated!